# How to select a list of objects as part of the constructor argument for a Hibernate group by query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, group-by

I'm trying to figure out how to select a list of objects as part of a Hibernate group-by query. I know how to do it a harder way, but I'm curious if there is some special sugar syntax that achieves the same thing.

Basically, I have a query of this structure:

```
select com.myapp.domain.TagSummary(
   tag.id, tag.term, tag.description, tag.synonyms, count(user)
)
from User user
   join user.tags tag
```

I'd like to store the `tag.synonyms` as a `List<Tag>`. Is that possible, or do I need to query the cross product and do the separation manually after the query results come back?

Alternatively, what I really want in the end is a list of synonym terms separated by commas. So if a tag is `spring` and it has synonym terms `spring-framework` and `spring-framework-3.1`, it would be great to put into the constructor the string `spring-framework, spring-framework-3.1`. Is that possible?

**EDIT**: I have learned that I can use group_concat() to achieve the second half of the functionality, but it's only available in MySQL. Is there a way to make it available in hsqldb as well? In Spring 3.1, how do I add this function to Hibernate? I know I should call something on `Configuration`, but I don't know what bean to access it by.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Object[]> result : query.list()) {    
    Tag tag = (Tag ) result[3];
    User user = (User) result[4];
}
```

You can get more information from this link

https://derrickpetzold.com/p/in-and-group-by-count-hibernate/